# Delete row with last timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

I'm trying to use this SQL query to delete a row from the table that has the latest date from the rows that have a specific member.

This query selects the correct row to delete:

```
SELECT *
FROM Swears
WHERE Date = ( 
  SELECT MAX(DATE) 
  FROM Swears
  WHERE Member = 36)
```

But this query doesn't delete the row.

```
DELETE
  FROM Swears
  WHERE Date = ( 
    SELECT MAX(DATE) 
    FROM Swears
    WHERE Member = 36)
```

Comment: Is date stored as timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM Swears
WHERE Member = 36
ORDER BY Date DESC 
LIMIT 1; -- for the first row
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM <table_name>
where <member_column> = <member_value>
ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1
```